Arthur Engel Number Theory Divisibility
Question is straightforward (Arthur Engel's Problem Solving Strategies Chapter 6 Problem 12, Page 131), I was stuck for a while then read the provided solution:
Show $$641 \vert 2^{32} + 1. \text{ No calculator allowed!}$$
The provided solution is
$$641 = 5^4 + 2^4 = 5 \cdot 2^7 + 1 \text{ divides both } 5^4 \cdot 2^{28} + 2^{32} \text{ and } 5^4 \cdot 2^{28} - 1.$$
$$\text{Then, it also divides their difference } 2^{32} + 1.$$
I was wondering what the key point of this question is and the main takeaway is supposed to be. For example, in the previous questions (i.e. If $n$is not a prime, then $2^{n} - 1$ is not prime, the key takeaway is that $x - 1 \vert x^{n} - 1$). Is there something special about the number $641$ that I am suppose to know? Or is it something about $x^{2^{k}} + 1$? I am a bit confused as to what kind of tools I use take away from this problem for math contests. Or can someone give me another problem with the same takeaway lesson from this? Thanks!

Worth noting that, if $2^{32}+1\equiv 0\pmod p$ then $2^{32}\equiv -1\pmod p$ so $2$ has order $64$ $\pmod p$.  Thus $64,|,p-1$.  It follows that $641$ should be one of the first primes one checks ($193, 257, 449,577$ also fit the pattern).  You can check it by iterated squaring....I do think it's asking a bit much to expect people to spot the given patterns.

I agree that this answer is hard to find and not particularly motivating. My instinct would be to start with $2^8 = 256$ and then compute $2^{16}$ and $2^{32}$ modulo $641$. This involves squaring $256$, dividing by $641$ to get the remainder $154$, then squaring $154$ and diving by $641$ to get the remainder $640$—doable by hand. Alternatively, if one spots $641 = 5\cdot2^7+1$, then $5\cdot 2^7 \equiv -1\pmod{641}$ and so $5^4\cdot 2^{28} \equiv 1\pmod{641}$; but $5^4 = 625 \equiv -16\pmod{641}$ which immediately gives $2^{32}\equiv-1\pmod{641}$.

The game of finding that factor $641$ is also interesting. IIRC Euler was aware of this helper lemma, and had a bit of luck in that $641$ is among the smallest primes $\equiv1\pmod{2^7}$ ($257$ being easier to rule out as a smaller Fermat number).

@Gur What is $\ell$? It's easier to use mod arithmetic (cf. my answer) vs. divisibility. But we can derive the divisibility form from the mod arithmetic, viz. OP is $,a = 2,, b = 5,, n = 643,$ in
$$n\mid \color{#0a0}{a^7b!+!1},,\color{#c00}{a^4!+!b^4},\Rightarrow, n\mid a^{32}!+!1 = a^{28}(\color{#c00}{a^4!+!b^4})-(\color{#0a0}{a^{28} b^4!-!1})\qquad $$
via Factor Theorem $\ \color{#0a0}{a^7b!-!c\mid (a^7b)^4!-!c^4},$ for $,c=-1;,$ simpler $,a^7b\equiv c,\Rightarrow, (a^7b)^4\equiv c^4.\ \ $

@BillDubuque, its typo, take $a=2^7$& $b=5$    $$F5=(1+ab)[a^4+(1-ab)(1+a^2b^2)]$$ where F5 is a fifth Fermat number.

It's an ad hoc method of computing (a multiple of) the order of $\,a\bmod n\,$ by elimination  when a nice "splitting" is obvious: $\, 1 + a^j\:\! b\equiv 0\equiv  \color{#c00}{a^\ell+b^k}\pmod{\!n},\, $ yielding
$\quad\  \bmod\ n\!:\ \ \ \ \  {-}1\ \equiv\:\,  a^{\large j}\, b,\,$  so by Power & Product Rules
$\quad\ \ {\rm above}^{\large k}\, \Rightarrow\, \pm1^{\phantom{|^{|^|}}}\!\! \equiv\ a^{\large jk} \color{#c00}{b^{\large k}} \equiv\ a^{\large jk}(- \color{#c00}{a^{\large \ell}})\equiv\, -a^{jk+\ell},\ $ i.e. succinctly
$\quad\ \bmod \ n\!:\ \ \ \ \  {-}1\, \equiv\:\,  a^{j} b\Rightarrow \pm1\equiv a^{jk}\color{#c00}{b^k} \equiv -a^{jk}\color{#c00}{a^\ell}\equiv -a^{jk+\ell}$
$\quad\ \bmod 641\!:\ \   {-}1\, \equiv\:\,  2^{7} 5\,\Rightarrow\, 1\equiv 2^{28}\color{#c00}{5^4} \equiv -2^{28}\color{#c00}{2^4}\equiv -2^{32}\ \ \ \ \rm [OP]$
$\quad\ \bmod 23\!:\ \ \ \ \ \ \ 1\, \equiv\:\,  2^{3} 3\,\Rightarrow\, 1\equiv 2^9\color{#c00}{3^3} \equiv 2^9\color{#c00}{2^2}\equiv 2^{11}\qquad \rm [others]$
$\quad\ \bmod 73\!:\ \ \ \,{-}1\, \equiv\:\,  2^{3} 3\,\Rightarrow\, 1\equiv 2^6\color{#c00}{3^4} \equiv 2^6\color{#c00}{2^3}\equiv 2^{9}$
$\quad\ \bmod 47\!:\ \ \ \ \ \ 1\ \equiv\:\,  2^{4} 3\,\Rightarrow\, 1\equiv 2^{20}\color{#c00}{3^5} \equiv 2^{20}\color{#c00}{3^3}\equiv 2^{23}$
$\quad\ \bmod 97\!:\ \ \ \ \ \  1\, \equiv\:\,  2^{5} 3\,\Rightarrow\, 1\equiv 2^{20}\color{#c00}{3^4} \equiv -2^{20}\color{#c00}{2^4}\equiv -2^{24}$
$\quad\ \bmod 251\!:\ {-}1\, \equiv\  2\, 5^3\!\Rightarrow\! {-}1\equiv 2\ \color{#c00}{5}^3 \equiv 2(\color{#c00}{2^8})^3\equiv 2^{25}$
$\quad\ \bmod 431\!:\, {-}1\, \equiv\  2^{4} 3^3\,\Rightarrow\, 1\equiv 2^{16}(\color{#c00}{3^{4}})^3 \equiv 2^{16}(\color{#c00}{2^9})^3\equiv 2^{43}$
Generally we can eliminate $\,b\,$ from $\,a^i b^j \equiv \pm1 \equiv a^k b^l$ when they are independent, and this may yield a short certificate  enabling efficient verification of some divisibility $\,n\mid a^m\pm1\,$ (e.g. analogous to Pratt primality certificates).
Historical Remark $ $ As mentioned in this old question, this method was used by Coxeter to verify the factor $641$ of the $5$'th Fermat number (which was mentioned in  Hardy & Wright's popular number theory textbook)

Wow!   I just want to compliment you on your posts.  They're always so fully explained and with colors.   You are the Modular Arithmetic guru.  Modular arithmetic being quintessential in number theory.


Is there something special about the number $641$ that I am suppose to know? Or is it something about $x^{2^k}+1$?

What is special is the historical background. If $2^m + 1$ is prime then $m$ must be a power of $2$, and Fermat checked that $2^{2^k}+1$ is prime when $k = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4$. He claimed that $2^{2^k}+1$ is prime for all integers $k \geq 0$. About $100$ years later Euler determined that this is not true by showing $2^{2^5} + 1 = 4,\!294,\!967,\!297$ is divisible by $641$ and thus it is composite. That is what makes this example interesting.
By the way, later calculations have led to no prime values of $2^{2^k}+1$ when $k \geq 5$ and it is now widely believed that $2^{2^k}+1$ is never prime when $k \geq 5$.
The way Euler was led to discover $641$ divides $2^{32}+1$ is described here. In modern language, the reasoning goes as follows. Let $p$ be a prime factor of $2^{32}+1$, so $2^{32} \equiv -1 \bmod p$ and thus $2^{64} \equiv 1 \bmod p$. That shows the order of $2 \bmod p$ divides $64$ but not $32$, so the order is $64$. Therefore $64 \mid (p-1)$ by Fermat's little theorem, so $p = 64n+1$. Run through $64n+1$ when $n = 1, 2, \ldots$ to check when it is prime, and when it is check whether it divides $4,\!294,\!967,\!297$. The number $64n+1$ is prime when $n = 3, 4, 7, 9, 10, 12, \ldots$ and we reach a prime factor of $2^{32}+1$ for the first time when $n = 10$, making $p = 640+1 = 641$:
$$
2^{2^5} + 1 = 4,\!294,\!967,\!297 = 641 \cdot 6700417
$$
So we only had to check $10$ numbers until we reached a proper factor of $2^{32}+1$, and the non-prime values of $64n+1$ when $n \leq 10$ are all easily detected because they are each divisible by $3$ or $5$.

Note that the question is not about how to discover the factor. Rather it about how to construct certain types of short certificates verifying the divisibility (e.g. analogous to Pratt's certificates of primality), cf. my answer.

@BillDubuque I agree, but the excerpt that I copied at the start of my answer suggests the OP might be unaware of how 641 was ever found in the first place, and it's an interesting story so I decided to write that here.

COMMENT (Just for fun).-This problem, it seems, has to be solved with some artifice that is not easily perceptible. Here another way.
Prove without calculator  that $2^{32}+1$ is divisible by $641$.
We have $\dfrac{2^{32}+1}{641}=\dfrac{16^8+1}{2\times16^2+8\times16+1}$. Consider the long division $f(x)=\dfrac{x^8+1}{2x^2+8x+1}$ so
$$f(x)=\frac{x^6}{2}-2x^5+\frac{31x^4}{4}-30x^3+\frac{929x^2}{8}-\frac{899x}{2}+\frac{27839}{16}+R(x)$$ where the rest $R(x)=\dfrac{-13470x-\dfrac{27823}{16}}{2x^2+8x+1}$.
We must have $f(16)\in\mathbb N$ and for this it is clearly enough to have $$S=\frac{27839}{16}+R(16)\in\mathbb N$$ We can verify that $S=1401\in\mathbb N$.
A nice remark.- The IBM $1401$ was of the first computers for the public and it appeared in 10/05/1959 sixty five years ago.

This question is not concerned with other ways . There is already a duplicate for that, which is where any such answer belongs. Please move your answer there.

@Bill Dubuque: Are you implying that I copied this other way of solving the problem from somewhere? I assure you that I have not and if you do not believe me that is your business and not mine. It is obvious that the “trick” that the O.P. exposes is somewhat difficult to guess and what I wanted was to give another way of solving the problem. Of course it is another way and it is pertinent to expose it here. I do not intend, sir, to withdraw this answer. Respectful greetings.

No, please read more carefully, This question is concerned with a specific method. The thread I linked does not, so your answer is on-topic there, but not here.
